# How to communicate with the AngularJS controller and the Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

### Please help me

I want to know how the helper methods of rails 3.2 can be used in **AngularJS**

Like for example :-

I am using **acts-as-messageable** gem in my application.

It has a helper_method called **send_message** which can be used in the controller of the rails application.

So how can I use this helper method inside of the **AngularJS controller**.

---

Basically what I need to know is "**How to communicate with AngularJS controller and the Rails Controller?**"

### Is it even possible to do so?Please **Justify**

---

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be implying AngulearJs runs on the server.  It does not.  AngularJS is a Javascript client side framework and rails is a server side Ruby framework.

That being said, I guess you could setup a restful endpoint in in rails and call it from an AngularJs client.  Which I would consider communication between the frameworks.

Comment: @above :: I do have the knowledge that angular is client side and rails is server side, but what I wanted to know is that **how should I do the setup so that both can communicate between the them**